# Print job in queue but nothing prints

Tags: printing, printer, windows-server-2012, network-printer

Brother L5850 connected via TCP to Server 2012 R2.

When I write to the print spooler to the UNC (\server\BL5850) the print job shows up in the print queue, then disappears quickly as if it printed, but nothing is printing.

Other printers, (Zebra, Cannon) print fine.

I am calling the Win32 spooler interface such as OpenPrinterA.

I have removed the printer from the server, rebooted, and added the printer new using server manager - print manager.

A test page when selected in windows will print.

What could be going on here?

Comment: Check your port and IP configurations to ensure you don't have that printer pointed to another queue because that could happen. So you see it disappear, it really prints to another physical printer. Otherwise, try a different document of just a text file with test 123 in it and see if that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
The Brother software (which said it was for Server 2012) wanted to install a printer on Windows Server 2012 as if it was installing it on Windows.  This would allow the test page to print, but a write to the spooler from an application would not print.  It would create a spooler job, but would not print that spooler job.  When the printer was installed correctly via the server print manager, it would still not print.

The fix, remove all the Brother Printers, and reboot the server several times to remove the remnants of the brother software.  Rebooting the server only once did not do it for me, it was the first thing I tried.  Then install the printer using the server Print Manager without running the Brother software.

Now when an application writes to the spooler, the print job both shows up in the spooler, and prints.